# How do I use Eloquent ORM to retrieve data from a database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new to MVC and do not understand it very much at all. I have a database with one table called `products`

I have a Model called `Product`which looks like

```
<?php

class Product extends Eloquent {

    // MASS ASSIGNMENT -------------------------------------------------------
    // define which attributes are mass assignable (for security)
    // we only want these 3 attributes able to be filled
    protected $fillable = array('type', 'brand', 'image');

}
```

I have a Route like so

```
Route::get('products', function()
{
    return View::make('products');
});
```

And my View looks like this

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    PRODUCTS

    @foreach($products as $product)

        {{ $product->type }}

    @endforeach
@stop
```

I see you can get all the rows like so `$products = Product::all();` but I don't understand WHERE this goes. Does it go in the View? Does it go in the Model? Does it go in the Route? My current @foreach loop just results in an `undefined variable: products`

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: That would usually go in your controller, and added to view withing controller, and use route just to declare endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started for now:

```
Route::get('products', function()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return View::make('products')->with('products', $products);
});
```

Comment: That's all I needed! Thank you! Every tutorial just sort of assumed you knew that.